# Sobreposição sobre a descrição das visualizações pelos títulos das questões

Tags: bug, status-pronto, design

Notei que **hoje** os títulos das questões estão a sobrepor os textos decritivos das visualizações das questões:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Houve alguma atualização?

**Nota:** *O mesmo observo para a página principal e a resolução esta em 100%.*

Comment: Notei isso também, talvez trocar por "visitas" resolva, se tiver o mesmo sentido em pt_PT.

Comment: Mudei para "visita(s)"

Comment: Oba, a correção já foi efetivada. Fechemos a questão? @Gabe

Comment: A tag status-pronto que o Gabe colcou indica que está resolvido, Cold. A ferramenta de fechamento (se é disso que você falou) tem outra finalidade.